# PHP Complete Object Graph not stored in Session

Tags: serialization, php

I have read other posts on stack overflow on the issue but my question is a little different..

When storing an object in the Session does PHP save the Complete Object Graph in the session?

I am having problems accessing some of the properties of the Object AFTER it is read from the Session.

The object i am storing has complex type properties with some of them being objects of classes that inherit from other classes, so serializing the object before storing it in the session might be a little "expensive".

What am i missing with Objects and their storage in the Session. Are there limits?

Thank you.

Comment: One obvious limit is: "Some types of data can not be serialized thus stored in sessions. It includes resource variables or objects with circular references (i.e. objects which passes a reference to itself to another object)." (http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex object graphs are serialized fine. Even cyclic references can be serialized. You can't serialize resources though, and certain built-in object types. Generally speaking, serialization is a very expensive operation. You should not rely on it as a shared memory strategy.